# only download updates after midnight and before 5am?

Tags: updates, system, schedule

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.  Is there a way to set the system to only download updates after midnight and before 5am?

Comment: It updates when ever you tell it to. there are no automatic updates. You can set them and use cron to set the timings but you really should not , IMO, if one breaks the system and it is unattended, you may have a hard time getting it back, see https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/automatic-updates.html

Comment: As mentioned you're in control of how the system by default you system will not automatically update. Updates can be installed when ever you tell your machines to install them